# JavaFX MenuBar on Pane on Borderpane (top) flickers

Tags: java, javafx, menubar

I'm writing a program in Java and I'm using JavaFX for the GUI,
using the MVC way.

The structure of the view I'm talking about is as follow:

[image: View structure]

The reason for this structure is because I want to keep my code clean & clear.

Inside the TopPane I want only a menuBar.

I've added this as follow:

```
public class TopPane extends Pane {
    private MenuBar menuBar;

    public TopPane() {
        initNodes();
        layoutNodes();
    }

   private void initNodes() {
        Menu[] menus = new Menu[3];
        menus[0] = new Menu("File");
        menus[1] = new Menu("Options");
        menus[2] = new Menu("Help");

        MenuItem[] menuItemsFile = new MenuItem[4];
        menuItemsFile[0] = new MenuItem("New game");
        menuItemsFile[1] = new MenuItem("Save game");
        menuItemsFile[2] = new MenuItem("Load game");
        menuItemsFile[3] = new MenuItem("Exit");
        menus[0].getItems().addAll(menuItemsFile);

        MenuItem options = new MenuItem("Options");
        menus[1].getItems().add(options);

        MenuItem help = new MenuItem("Help");
        menus[2].getItems().add(help);

        menuBar = new MenuBar();
        menuBar.getMenus().addAll(menus);
    }

    private void layoutNodes() {
        menuBar.setMinWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        menuBar.useSystemMenuBarProperty().set(true);
        getChildren().add(menuBar);
    }

    public MenuBar getMenuBar() {
        return menuBar;
    }
}
```

In gameview I do the following:

```
public class GameView extends BorderPane {
    private TopPane topPane;
    private LeftPane leftPane;
    private PlayerView playerView; //centerpane
    private RightPane rightPane;

    public GameView() {
        initNodes();
        layoutNodes();
    }

    private void initNodes() {
        topPane = new TopPane();
        leftPane = new LeftPane();
        playerView = new PlayerView();
        rightPane = new RightPane();
    }

    private void layoutNodes() {
        this.setStyle("-fx-background-color:  #2a2a2a");

        this.setTop(topPane);

        Rectangle2D screenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
        double screenHeight = screenBounds.getHeight();
        int topMargin = 25;
        if (screenHeight >= 1050) {
            topMargin = 150;
        }
        System.out.println(screenHeight);

        setMargin(leftPane, new Insets(topMargin, 0, 0, 50));
        this.setLeft(leftPane);

        setMargin(playerView, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 25));
        this.setCenter(playerView);

        this.setRight(rightPane);
    }
}
```

It shows the menubar succesfully but the problem is that when I click one of the menus, the menuItems just flickers and dissapear immediatly. I think this is because I extend topPane with Pane. But without it couldn't work obviously, and if I extend from menuBar (and delete the variable Menubar), my rightPane & PlayerView won't be added to my GameView for some mysterious dark reason I couldn't figure out (yet) :)

Anybody able to help me? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Remove this line: `menuBar.setMinWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);`  and extend `StackPane` rather than `Pane` then everything will work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to DVarga :

- Remove menuBar.setMinWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
- Extend StackPane instead of Pane

This works perfectly!